# coverflow android:how to download images from gallery

Tags: android, coverflow

coverflow android:how to download images from gallery.
I have used code from this site  http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html
but it uses images from resources,I need to load all the images from gallery and then display it using coverflow effect. Please somebody help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to apply lazy loading for images in coverflow

take took at this

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Comment: first you need to filter images data from SD card. and you need to get path for each images and decode the Image from the file-path as  Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
ImageView.setImageDrawable(bitmap);

Comment: above link expalin about downloading images from web. I want to download images from gallery and then need to apply coverflow effect on it.I am able to download images from gallery but coverflow effect is not working.

Comment: data into gallery comes from sd card.just you need to changes the url with path of image from sd card. you need to read file from sd card as bitmap, and then send this bitmap to gallery adapter.